# Trying to implement Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, axios

So this is the axios implementation

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  console.log("INTERCEPTOR CALLED");
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

And this is the function which is establishing connection. In this first I am updating the state and then requesting server and if something goes south then reverting the state back to original state.

```
handleDelete = async (post) => {
const orginialPosts = this.state.posts;
const posts = this.state.posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id);
this.setState({ posts });
try {
  await axios.delete(apiEndpoint + "/" + post.id);
  throw new Error("Pandemic. xd");
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("handle delete catch block");
  if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404)
    alert("This post has already been deleted");
  alert("Something Failed while deleting a post!");
  this.setState({ posts: orginialPosts });
}
};
```

So in console it should print :-
INTERCEPTOR CALLED
handle delete catch block

Instead it is printing :-
handle delete catch block

I can't figure out why it's happening.

And one more thing is there any way to throw error with specific code, something like :-

```
throw new Error status(404).
```

Or creating the whole express handler and then sending response with status code 404 is the only way.

I just wanted to create a Error with status code 404.

Comment: maybe try `axios.delete().then( data => throw new Error('404'))`. You are currently throwing error outside axios.

Comment: But I am using axios interceptor that means it should intercept the error first and then pass it ahead. Actually I am referring some videos and he implemented it the same way and got the desired results. I'm not using his axios version though.

Comment: what you are doing now is throwing a error outside axios, but expecting axios to handle the error.

Comment: I read axios documentaion and in axios intercept error function it was written - "Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger". I checked network tab in chrome and there was 200 and 204 so the error created by the "throw new Error (" ")" won't pass throw axios error handling. I think it's the answer why it's not intercepting. What do you think ?

Comment: Ic, then you just modify your url to a non existence url and you can get a 4xx error

Comment: I literally can't find single url responding 404 status code error.

Comment: why not? just use `/iadhsaiuhdiausdhiuwehdiw`. 404 means non existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved, the issue was `throw new Error("");` was sending a status code of 200 or 204 and the axios interceptor catches error outside the range of 2xx.
The above code was fine, it was just status code messing up.